# TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to assign a value to a variable after converting it to an integer. My code:

```
timStamp = int(time.time()) // 30
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

I also tried:

```
timStamp = time.time() // 30
```

This time I got:

```
TypeError: 'float' does not support the buffer interface
```

I have already searched in Google, but I didn't find the answer I was looking for.
N:B: I am working with python 3 and my full source code is given below
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10584501/

Comment: Show us code that we can copy-paste into a fresh Python session to reproduce the error, and show us the complete error message. I doubt the error is coming from this line.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The code you have provided **does not** cause the error you report.

Comment: I am sorry that i did not format it before posting here. But please give me answer. If your do have any question please ask in the comment but do not skip it. Please

Comment: The commenters are not complaining about formatting, they are complaining that you did not show the code that exhibits the problem. The line you show does *not* cause that error.

Comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29005414/edit) and include the full traceback: start with a line `Traceback (most recent call last):` and until the last line with `TypeError` in it. Don't post *all* your code; [create a minimal but complete code example that leads to the error instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the full traceback, to see where the error happens. In this case the code yields,

```
/tmp/test2.py in get_totp(secret)
     41     #timStamp = int (time.time() // 60)
     42     timStamp = int(time.time()) // 60
---> 43     return get_hotp(secret, base64.b16encode(timStamp))
TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

So the problem is that `base64.b16encode` expects a byte string and was given an int or a float instead.

However, I can understand the confusion as this exception is raised one line later than the line you provided.